# can some verify that the column headed by a+1 is correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

can some verify that the column headed by a+1 is correct?

my ans, by there is some thing wrong. can some one explain to me where and what is wrong with this answer?

since $a^3 = a+1, a^4 = a^2 + a$, than

(a + 1) * 0 = 0

(a + 1) * 1 = a + 1

$(a + 1) a = a^2 +a$

$(a + 1)  (a + 1) = (a + 1)^2 = a^2 + 1$

$(a + 1) * a^2 = a^3 + a^2 = a + 1 + a^2$

$(a + 1)  (a^2 + 1) = a^3 + a^2 +  + 1 = a^2$

$(a+1) (a^2 + a) = a^3 + a = 1$

$(a+a) (a^2 + a + 1) = 1 + a + 1 = a$

Comment: Are we supposed to have divine inspiration and just know that you're talking about the multiplication table of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z_2[a]/(a^3+a+1)$?

Comment: It is not at all clear what the question is, and it is therefore difficult to judge whether or not your computations are valid. Please provide more context!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are working in a very different number system, this is how I'd expand $(a+1)^2$:

$(a+1)^2=a^2+a+a+1=a^2+2a+1$

---

Edited to correct this case:

If $a^3=a+1$, then these may be simplified:

$(a+1)(a^2+1)=a^3+a+a^2+1=a^3+a^2+a+1 = a^2+2a+2$

$(a+1)(a^2+a)=a^3+a^2+a^2+a=a^3+2a^2+a=2a^2+2a+1$

$(a+a)(a^2+a+1)=2a(a^2+a+1)=2a^3+2a^2+2a=2a+2a^2+2a=2a^2+4a+2$

The error initially is that the distributive property isn't being applied properly as each combination has to appear in the product, assuming a non-modulo 2 case:

- $(b+c)(d+e)=bd+be+cd+ce$
- $(b+c)(d+e+f)=bd+be+bf+cd+ce+cf$

Though if you are working modulo 2, these computations are incomplete, but this wasn't stated in the question that the co-efficients of these polynomials are in that field.  I'm presuming all the Integers, Rationals or Reals.

In mod 2, those calculations would end up being:

$(a+1)(a^2+1)=a^3+a+a^2+1=a^3+a^2+a+1 = a^2+2a+2 = a^2$

$(a+1)(a^2+a)=a^3+a^2+a^2+a=a^3+2a^2+a=2a^2+2a+1=1$

$(a+a)(a^2+a+1)=2a(a^2+a+1)=2a^3+2a^2+2a=2a+2a^2+2a=2a^2+4a+2=0$ , though this could be computed this way:

$(a+a)(a^2+a+1)=2a(a^2+a+1)=0a(a^2+a+1)=0$

Comment: i see, so error is at $a^3$ = a+1? this should be $a^3 = a$?

Comment: @kate, I had a typo in those expressions but I suspect your issue is in the distributive property being applied correctly.